# Add/remove dropdown list items based on radio selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, the html:

```
<input type="radio" name="selectrad" class="rad" data-min="2" />
<input type="radio" name="selectrad" class="rad" data-min="5" />

<select name="minimum" class="minimum">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9<option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

What I've been trying to do is append or remove options from the dropdown based on the value of 'data-min' on the radio button clicked. So if 'data-min' contains 5, only options 5-10 will show. I've tried finding the difference between the two and adding or subtracting that way with no luck.

I'm trying to avoid the easy way of just grabbing the radio value, looping through with `for (i=0; i<min; i++)` and replacing the html, as this code should be as fast and efficient as possible.

Comment: Based on the value of data-min how, exactly? You need to explain how the value of the data-min attribute on your radio button relates to the options in the select list. Also, including any code you've already got (even if it didn't work) is better than including nothing at all.

Comment: Looping the options will take just few milliseconds, that can't be any issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure if there is a way better than looping and generating content till the point where you want. And I've looped and generated content with way more entries, never gave me an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like below help? Its a basic code to which you can add based on your conditions. If the data-min is 2, everything from 3 to 10 will be hidden, and it its '5', everything before 5 would be hidden

```
               $(document).ready(function(){
           $("input[name='selectrad']").click(function(){
               // console.log($(this).attr("data-min"));
                if($(this).attr("data-min") === '2'){
                    $(".minimum").find("option").show();
                    var min = $(".minimum").find("option:gt(1)");
                    min.hide();
                } else {
                    $(".minimum").find("option").show();
                    var max = $(".minimum").find("option:lt(4)").hide();
                    max.hide();
                }
           })
        })
```

Comment: This is excellent thank you! I modified your answer a bit since it only needed to be numbers less than either that needed removing.